# Are references possible in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, reference

Is it possible to assign references to objects in JSON? I have data that looks like this:

```
[{
  name:"name",
  Parent:[{
    name:"parentName"
    Parent:[{
       .....//and so on
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I need to traverse it in JavaScript and also change the person's `name`. How can I do this?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have explicit objects references. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will traverse those values and perform some operations like changing name of the person.

Comment: If this is about JSON, then it does not have anything to do with JavaScript, and vice versa. If you want references you have to give your objects IDs and use these throughout your structure. Like with XML.

Comment: You can use a for-each loop (in whatever language you're using) to get all the properties of an object. Felix, why do you say that about JSON not having anything to do with Javascript?

Comment: @taz: JSON is like XML... it's a data exchange format. XML is not associated with any language in particular. Of course if the question is about how to process JSON in JavaScript, then there is a relation. I just want people be more clear about the actual issue of their question, because JavaScript literal notation is often mistaken for JSON.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. You can specify the path to the parent as a string and evaluate that at runtime, but as JSON is just strings, integers, arrays, and dictionaries, you can't use references.

Comment: You can also solve it manually, by including a reference table object. Like a dictionary. But it's not a perfect solution for sure.

Comment: What i meant was, do anybody know of well-known data structure format could allow me to do store arbitrary arrays that might reference each other members?

Comment: @HLL As far as I know, no. You will need to do binary serialization on the data and create a class that stores a pointer. That's ultimately how references work; they're either serialized as pointers, or they store a string representation of the path (like what XSLT uses).

Answer (score 13):

Old question but some possibly new answers like **JSON Spec** and **JSON Reference** https://json-spec.readthedocs.io/reference.html

```
[{
  "name": "John",
 },
 {
  "name" : "Jack",
  "parent": {"$ref": "#/0"}
 },
 ...
]
```

or possibly better with **JSON Path** syntax http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

```
[{
  "name": "John",
 },
 {
  "name" : "Jack",
  "parent": {"$ref": "$.[?(@.name=='John')]"}
 }, 
...
]
```